# Geodesics on Compact Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact, connected smooth manifold. If $p, q$ are points in $M$, is there always a geodesic that goes from $p$ to $q$?

I know that this is certainly not true if $M$ is not compact, but I couldn't find a counterexample for the compact case.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks,

S.

Comment: Notice that your manifold has to have a metric for the question to make sense (you could get by with a projective class of connections on $M$...)

Comment: Indeed, I should have written "Riemannian manifold", I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. This is part of the classical Hopf-Rinow theorem, *q.v.*

Comment: Thanks Mariano. I don't know Hopf-Rinow yet - I'm still about 70 pages away from it! =)

Answer (score 1):

Just minimize the energy of the path in the homotopy class of paths connecting p and q.

Comment: What's the missing step here?  Presumably there's some fact about the space of paths from p to q in a compact manifold that doesn't hold in general that I just don't know about.

Comment: If the manifold is not complete, then you have a problem. Take for instance R^2 with the origin removed, p=(-1,0) and q=(1,0). Then there is no geodesic between them. On the other hand, if the Riemannian metric makes the manifold complete, you've won!